# Autolayout Contraints cannot be set for UIViews?

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints

I am using autolayout in an application. When i pin constraints for any UI element like UILabel or UIButton or UIScrollView in a View Controller, these are pinned successfully but none of the constraints work when it comes to UIView. What can possibly be the issue?

Comment: Show us the constraints you're having trouble with and explain exactly what the problem is. Otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: Following is the screenshot of the constraints i have pinned. For iPhone6 it is showing the "View" on left corner leaving space on the right side.

https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=1450293581945389&set=a.1408746182766796.1073741826.100008942827374&type=1&theater

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: No error has been generated - UI is disturbed for iPhone6, empty space is shown to right side of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Constraints weren't working because i simulated the view controller with iPhone-4-inch size. Setting the simulated metric of size equal to "inferred" solved the problem. All constraints are now successfully pinned.